# list::iterator invalid for moved-to list?

Tags: c++, list, iterator, move-semantics

I have used a decent amount of C++, but not so much `std::list` ..
In my current project I need a `std::list<..>` data member, as well as keep track to a position in the list with a `std::list<..>::iterator`. The object must also be movable, but a default move constructor is not possible in my case. Here `std::list` does something that surprises me.

Consider

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void test() {
    T l { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    cout << "l = "; for(const auto& e: l) cout << e << " "; cout << endl;
    auto pos = find(l.begin(), l.end(), 6);
    if (pos == l.end()) cout << "l end\n";

    cout << "---- moving l > lmv ----" << endl;
    T lmv { std::move(l) };
    cout << "l = "; for(const auto& e: l) cout << e << " "; cout << endl;
    cout << "lmv = "; for(const auto& e: lmv) cout << e << " "; cout << endl;
    if (pos == l.end()) cout << "l end\n";
    if (pos == lmv.end()) cout << "lmv end\n";
}

int main() {
    cout << "___vector___\n";
    test<vector<int>>();
    cout << "___list___\n";
    test<list<int>>();
}
```

This outputs

```
___vector___
l = 1 2 3 4 5 
l end
---- moving l > lmv ----
l = 
lmv = 1 2 3 4 5 
lmv end
___list___
l = 1 2 3 4 5 
l end
---- moving l > lmv ----
l = 
lmv = 1 2 3 4 5 
l end
```

I.e. the iterator that pointed to the moved-from `list`s end, does not point to the moved-to `list`s end.
But it does for `vector`, which is what I would always expect, if iterators are essentially pointers. Why is `list` different? Memory location of elements should not change with move .. does `list`s move change list iterators? Why?

I am using "g++.exe (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.2.0"
under MSYS2 on Windows 10

Comment: Your program blows up royally with an `assert()` when run under Visual C++, debug mode.

Comment: Also, comparing iterators that point to different containers does not make sense.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/list) the iterators in `std::list` are valid after moving as are [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)'s

Comment: Though there does seem to be an exception for the `end` iterator which can be invalidated

Comment: @Daniel Langr I would agree, if the containers were actually different, but it is a move .. ?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I forgot to add #include <algorithm> in the question, that was probably it?

Comment: My guess is that it's the `end` iterator invalidation mentioned by @AlanBirtles. Since the element isn't found, `pos` will be the `end` iterator. Then you move the container, and you compare the (possibly invalidated) `end` iterator from `l` with the `end` iterator of `lmv`. That comparison is invalid to begin with (you can't compare iterators from two different containers).

Comment: @Shiwayari -- The error is not a compilation error.  The debug runtime actually will detect what others have noted already.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I see, I am in Eclipse without such tools. Anyway, I think it is cleared up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterators should be preserved when moving a container.

However `end` iterators of a container don't point to an element and are therefore allowed to be [invalidated when moving a container](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2321).

If you change your code to work with `begin` rather than `end` then it works [as you expect](https://godbolt.org/z/63b6Pj).

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void test() {
    T l { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    cout << "l = "; for(const auto& e: l) cout << e << " "; cout << endl;
    auto pos = find(l.begin(), l.end(), 1);
    if (pos == l.begin()) cout << "l begin\n";

    cout << "---- moving l > lmv ----" << endl;
    T lmv { std::move(l) };
    cout << "l = "; for(const auto& e: l) cout << e << " "; cout << endl;
    cout << "lmv = "; for(const auto& e: lmv) cout << e << " "; cout << endl;
    if (pos == l.begin()) cout << "l begin\n";
    if (pos == lmv.begin()) cout << "lmv begin\n";
}

int main() {
    cout << "___vector___\n";
    test<vector<int>>();
    cout << "___list___\n";
    test<list<int>>();
}
```

Note that comparing the iterators from two different containers is undefined behaviour so the final `pos == l.begin()` is undefined behaviour and visual studio's debug builds at least will throw assertions when running this code.

I imagine your original code works because the `std::vector` `end` iterator is usually just implemented as pointing to one after the last element. I would imagine the `std::list` end iterator holds a null pointer and a pointer to the list.

Comment: I see.. thanks. I'm aware of the horror at the end of my test function - this was basically intentional UB just to see something, because I had no idea what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you add such horrible lines at the end of your test function
(this is totally incorrect, the sanitizer will insult you!),
you can see that in the case of a `vector` the `end()` iterator
designates something which is past-the-end of the buffer containing
the stored elements, but in the case of a `list` the end iterator
designates some kind of marker which is stored inside the `list`
structure itself.

Then, after moving, the buffer of the vector is still the same
but it does not belong to `l` anymore, so the address past-the-end
of this buffer is equivalent to `end()` for `lmv`.

On the other hand, after moving the `list`, `pos` which designated
an address *inside* `l` still designated the same address (although
`l` is moved from) but does not designate the `end()` marker inside
`lvm` which didn't even exist when `pos` was initialised.

```cpp
    std::cout << "pos: " << (void *)(&*pos) << '\n';
    std::cout << "l: " << (void *)(&l) << '\n';
    std::cout << "l.begin(): " << (void *)(&*l.begin()) << '\n';
    std::cout << "l.end(): " << (void *)(&*l.end()) << '\n';
    std::cout << "lmv: " << (void *)(&lmv) << '\n';
    std::cout << "lmv.begin(): " << (void *)(&*lmv.begin()) << '\n';
    std::cout << "lmv.end(): " << (void *)(&*lmv.end()) << '\n';
```